# TypeError: (0 , _index.default) is not a function when using Babel as a library in a Rollup bundle

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollupjs

I am trying to include Babel and rollup.js in an application bundle (which itself is bundled using Rollup) that is to be run in the browser (for transpiling and bundling inside the browser). I have rollup working without `@rollup/plugin-babel` enabled. As soon as I import `@rollup/plugin-babel` (and thereby Babel) in the application code, I get this error after calling rollup():

```
babelv.min.js:101604 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _index.default) is not a function
at NodePath.traverse (babelv.min.js:101604)
at Scope.crawl (babelv.min.js:68561)
at Scope.init (babelv.min.js:68505)
at NodePath.setScope (babelv.min.js:100024)
at NodePath.setContext (babelv.min.js:100040)
at new File (babelv.min.js:106640)
at normalizeFile$ (babelv.min.js:120308)
at tryCatch (babelv.min.js:10464)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (babelv.min.js:10681)
at Generator.next (babelv.min.js:10517)
```

I am using this Babel configuration:

```
"presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": 3
    }]
]
```

I have the core-js/regenerator-runtime stuff figured out and working properly.

Looking at the Babel source inside the package (`@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js`), the `(0, ...` syntax is present, so it isn't being mangled by Babel:

```
traverse(visitor, state) {
     (0, _index.default)(this.node, visitor, this.scope, state, this);
}
```

I've looked at other questions with similar errors that ended up being caused by incorrect named/default imports and circular dependencies, but neither appear to be the case here. I'm wondering if it's possibly a bug. Or, maybe more likely, I need some special plugins or configuration to properly bundle Babel.

Comment: It's because rollup's CommonJS plugin can't handle circular dependencies. I don't know what to do now...

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using Webpack. Works great.